# UIView removeFromSuperview

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewanimationtransition

The removeFromSuperview method actually pulls off the image very quickly, is there a way to remove it in a animated fashion. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code example here

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/37467-removefromsuperview-animation-transition.html

Answer (score 7):

If you're targeting iOS4 (code snippet from UIView docs):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                 animations:^{ table.alpha = 0.0; }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){ [table removeFromSuperview]; }];
```

Answer (score 0):

1) insert your new subview (index of 0 so it's hidden) onto the view stack.

```
    [window insertSubview:myNewView atIndex:0];
```

2) Then animation the view out (straight from the docs) is:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
       animations:^{ view.alpha = 0.0; }
       completion:^(BOOL finished){ [view removeFromSuperview]; }]
```